# How to search, find, and select data from rows and copy to new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I need to build a macro to find the row desired in sheet 1, which is predetermined by the value in column A, and then copy the values from that same row for specific columns (`D:F` in this example) into a predetermined spot on sheet 2.

Unfortunately I cant make the macro always refer to the same cells because the data won't always start on 1A, it may start on row 3 or 10 or wherever. The columns should stay in the same place every time, but I will definitely need the macro to do a search for the desired contents in column A.

Also I don't want to copy the entire row over because there is more data in the columns that follow in sheet 1 that is completely irrelevant to what I need in sheet 2.

Below is an example of what I need to happen to better explain:

Sheet 1 (Original Data)

```
  |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |   F   |   G   |
--+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
1 | Title | M2011 | M2012 | M2013 | M2014 | M2015 |  TTM  |
2 |   1A  |   1B  |   1C  |   1D  |   1E  |   1F  |   1G  |
3 |   2A  |   2B  |   2C  |   2D  |   2E  |   2F  |   2G  |
4 |   3A  |   3B  |   3C  |   3D  |   3E  |   3F  |   3G  | 
5 |   4A  |   4B  |   4C  |   4D  |   4E  |   4F  |   4G  |
```

Sheet 2 (Desired Result)

```
  |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |  
--+-------+-------+-------+-------+
1 | Title | M2013 | M2014 | M2015 | 
2 |   2A  |   2D  |   2E  |   2F  | 
3 |   4A  |   4D  |   4E  |   4F  | 
4 |   3A  |   3D  |   3E  |   3F  |
```

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: Unfortunately none that relates to what I asked given that I dont know how to write it. All I have so far is the creation of the new sheet I need and the formatting of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to make the proposed formula search for what I needed so I just ended up using this and then deleting the extra columns it pulled. Not the fanciest or most efficient way, but got the job done

```
 Sub DesperateTimes()
    Dim Cell As Range
    For i = 25 To 100
    Sheets("sheet1").Select
    If Cells(i, "A").Value = "Title" Then
    Rows(i).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("sheet2").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
    Sheets("sheet1").Select
    If Cells(i, "A").Value = "2A" Then
    Rows(i).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("sheet2").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
    Sheets("sheet1").Select
    If Cells(i, "A").Value = "4A" Then
    Rows(i).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("sheet2").Select
    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
    Sheets("sheet1").Select
    If Cells(i, "A").Value = "3A" Then
    Rows(i).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("sheet2").Select
    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
    Sheets("sheet2").Select
    Columns("E:EZ").Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    Next i

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is piece of code that will help you

```
Sub SetGrade()

Dim srcSheet As Worksheet
Dim trgtSheet As Worksheet
Dim foundVal As Object
Dim i

Set srcSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set trgtSheet = Workbooks("book2").Sheets(1)

For i = 1 To trgtSheet.Cells(trgtSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'iterate through column A in target sheet

    Set foundVal = srcSheet.Columns(1).Find(srcSheet.Range("a" & i).Value) 'take value from column a target sheet then look for it in column A sourcesheet

    srcSheet.Range(foundVal.Offset(0, 3), foundVal.Offset(0, 5)).Copy Destination:=trgtSheet.Range("B" & i) ' take cells columns D:F from found row and paste them into range starting at column B and row from which search criteria was taken

Next i

End Sub
```

You need to adjust the workbook names etc. to your situation

Comment: I have put your code in to my sheet but am not sure how to come up with the desired results. I'm not too sure whether the code does this or not (i'm pretty new with excel macros but I am not seeing where the code looks for the proper row depending on the contents of column A.

Comment: Basically I need it to search for a value in column A (say in the ranges of 1:250), once the value is found, select the cells a couple of columns over (as per the example), paste them at the desired place, and then repeat for the next row I need. I have made the changes to the workbook names but still don't see where the macro is searching for what I am looking for.

Comment: I need the equivalent of the following code (that I used for something else) but to search for the value in the rows instead of the columns, and rather than copy the full row, just selected values a few columns over.                                                                                                                Dim cell As Range
        For i = 1 To 200
        Sheets("Download").Select
        If Cells(2, i).Value = "Symbol" Then
        Columns(i).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Narrowed").Select
        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If

Comment: added commentaries to the code, should clear your doubts a bit